# How to reduce the bundle size of flutter web?

Tags: flutter, lazy-loading, flutter-web

I am developing web app using flutter. My question , Is there any lazy , preloading  routing options in flutter like angular . So that I can reduce the initial time for showing the first screen without loading other screens .

Comment: Facing the same problem for a pretty large app. the bundle is 2.5 MB and 900 Kb gzipped.
after googling, I think I will keep the apps separate from a regular html landing page where I download the bundle in the background.

Comment: Facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

One way of reducing the size of your bundle is by removing unnecessary plugins added to your pubspec.yaml file. The build file for web is usually small and shouldn't be that large unless there's a lot of assets included in your build.

As for preloading pages, you can consider using [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) - this caches the PageView children for quicker load times. Of course, pages far from the viewport are usually disposed and rebuilt again depending on the size of the Widget.